# IIS7 give ApplicationPoolIdentity access to a network location

Tags: security, iis, active-directory, windows-server-2008

I have a site in IIS7 that runs under `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.

Is it possible to give the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` access to network files?

I know that I can give access to local files by giving rights to the user: `iisapppool\{apppoolname}` but is there a way to give this ID access to files on the network?

Answer (score 12):

ApplicationPoolIdentity is a `LOCAL` user (generated by IIS, its identity is not known until runtime) thus any attempt to access anything on the network would result in it using the `COMPUTER$` account.

Using ActiveDirectory you should then be able to grant the `COMPUTER$` account access to the files you want.

Alternatively, using ActiveDirectory you could create a Domain User account, configure the application pool identity to use that domain user, and grant that user access to the network files.

Read more [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) about Application Pool Identities.